# Is it good practice to convert json objects returned by rest api to instances of ES6 classes?

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I would like to ask if you convert JS objects returned by rest api (via ajax calls) to instances of javascript class (e.g. ES6/ES2015 class) or you keep the data from rest api as plain objects?

Comment: Data is just data. If you need to an object based on that data, instantiate a new object with that data as constructor input.

Comment: ECMAScript 2015 "classes" are just syntactic sugar, there is no difference from "classes" in previous versions.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depend on the use case. I have a web application that have a very complex object and I ended up creating a class with complex methods to grab the information that I wanted.

But for most cases I think you don't need to parse json -> object -> class you can use directly the json object.

**UPDATE: Just to make my example richer**

On my use case I have a list of ports and each port have a list of facilities with `onlineDate`. Sometimes I need to ask questions like:

1. How many online facilities this port have?
2. Is this port online?
3. Is there at least one online facility?
4. Is there any future/past facility?

To avoid computing this every time, I just wrapped this in a class with methods like `hasOnlineFacility()` to avoid repetition.

Comment: In this project you wrap all objects got from server into classes or just in some cases when you need it?

Comment: Since I created a class for this particular resource, every time I deal with the same resource I instantiate new objects but when I'm using simpler ones I just use as plain JavaScript objects.